# Is there a way to append to each vector element with the respective name of list element?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Here is my list of vectors.

```
j = list(x = c('apple', 'avocado'), y = c('banana', 'beetroot'))
```

Here are the contents of j.

```
$x
[1] "apple"   "avocado"

$y
[1] "banana"   "beetroot"
```

Here is the desired output.

```
$x
[1] "x_apple"   "x_avocado"

$y
[1] "y_banana"   "y_beetroot"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `purrr::imap()`:

```
library(purrr)
imap(j, ~ paste0(.y, "_", .x))
```

Output

```
$x
[1] "x_apple"   "x_avocado"

$y
[1] "y_banana"   "y_beetroot"
```

The "i" in `imap()` means index, and conveniently lets you pass both the elements of a vector and its names into a function.

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can use `Map` -

```
Map(function(x, y) paste(x, y, sep = '_'), names(j), j)

#$x
#[1] "x_apple"   "x_avocado"

#$y
#[1] "y_banana"   "y_beetroot"
```

Comment: You can even pass the arguments straight into `Map` - `Map(paste, names(j), j, sep="_")`